# Bookmarks in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipse has a feature called Bookmarks where one can make notes against specific lines of code and also a View to see all these bookmarks. Does IntelliJ have anything like this natively or as an add-on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

on mac you can add a bookmark with f3, then command-f3 will bring up all of your bookmarks and you can add notes to them individually.

Edited to add: for windows/linux it's f11 and shift-f11

Comment: Official documentation links: [Navigating with Bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-with-bookmarks.html), [Managing Bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-bookmarks.html).